# Alternative to href, likely without <a>

Tags: html, css

**Edit:** This question doesn't make sense, and my actual problem was that I had an `<a>` tag inside another `<a>` tag.

I'm in a scenario where it seems like I cannot use  tags for links. Is there any JavaScript alternative, that functions the same way?

I have a string of text, and I have parts of that string which I want to have as links. This string has a fixed width of 200px, and needs the CSS `overflow: ellipsis` (Thus it should not wrap)

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LzL9cv00/4/

Comment: What makes you think you can't use `<a>`? Where is your [mcve]? You haven't put any relevant code in the question, and the code you link to doesn't include `<a>` anywhere.

Comment: @Quentin What makes me believe I cannot use multiple <a> tags is that the overflow property requires a fixed with; Something that is not as easy to get if you break up the string into <a> elements.

Comment: @Quentin My problem seems to have been that I wrapped an <a> element inside another <a> element, which makes at least Chrome bug out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you would create links.

```
   <p>
      So here we got <a href="#">Link1</a> and <a href="#">Link2</a>!
    </p>
```

Suggested change:

https://jsfiddle.net/LzL9cv00/6/

Comment: why do you need to put <a> tag inside another <a> tag?